# Web Audio API microphone not working on Chrome Canary

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I am completely puzzeled because this is something that worked for me few days ago and now it doesn't.
I can't get audio input from microphone with the Web Audio Api or getUserMedia.
I am using Mac & Chrome Canary 29.
I don't get the mic input in the following link:
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

In the system's mic preferences I do see input from the mic.

It worked few days ago, I have to develop an app with Web Audio API... Don't know what to do.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, I was at that link yesterday. Have the same problem in Canary as you, doesn't react to the mic even if it's working. Guess it's a temporary hick-up in Canary (or an API change - haven't checked).

Comment: Does anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: Unbelievable, it is working on Chromium...

Comment: I working right now on project which involves getUserMedia and Audio API and I found interesting bug: you have camera icon in right side of address bar. If you set there any device except "default" you'll always get channel buffers filled with zeroes. Maybe you fall into this also?

Comment: No, I can't get worked demo too. I'm on non-dev `27.0.1453.110` version and demo worked in Tuesday. Maybe author changed source code?

Answer (score 2):

We had a few bad days of audio in Canary.  Try again.  (I'm the author of http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/.)

Comment: It is still not working in Chrome Canary, however it is working in Chromium. The weird thing is that it is not only your website - the problem is in every app using the Web Audio API...

Comment: Wow. Is there source code for these? Also, will mic input work on mobile devices?

Comment: +Joel yeah, all my demos are on Github (most have links from inside the apps) - github.com/cwilso.  And yes, AudioRecorder and even Vocoder work on Android (and partially on iOS).